# Unresolved external symbol linker error for a function not even declared?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

normally when i get this error, I go looking for a function i forgot to define, but i'm getting this from the assignment operator of a class, and i never declared it. The error goes like this:

`1>SYNC_D3D11Model_Defs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct SYNC::Vector2 & __thiscall SYNC::Vector2::operator=(struct SYNC::Vector2 const &)" (??4Vector2@SYNC@@QAEAAU01@ABU01@@Z) referenced in function "public: struct VERTEX_TYPE & __thiscall VERTEX_TYPE::operator=(struct VERTEX_TYPE const &)" (??4VERTEX_TYPE@@QAEAAU0@ABU0@@Z)`

`1>SYNC_D3D11Model_Defs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct SYNC::Vector4 & __thiscall SYNC::Vector4::operator=(struct SYNC::Vector4 const &)" (??4Vector4@SYNC@@QAEAAU01@ABU01@@Z) referenced in function "public: struct VERTEX_TYPE & __thiscall VERTEX_TYPE::operator=(struct VERTEX_TYPE const &)" (??4VERTEX_TYPE@@QAEAAU0@ABU0@@Z)`

which essentially boils down to, VERTEX_TYPE::operator= is trying to use `SYNC::Vector2::operator=(const SYNC::Vector2 &)` and `SYNC::Vector4::operator=(SYNC::Vector2 &)` but cannot find the defintions. The problem with this is, 1) I never declared, defined, or used the assignment operator in VERTEX_TYPE, 2) even if i had, those functions are indeed defined within the .cpp. Here see for yourself. These are the two offending structs and their definitions.

SYNC_Vectors.h

```
#ifndef SYNC_VECTORS_H
#define SYNC_VECTORS_H

#include <cmath>

namespace SYNC
{
    struct Vector2
    {
        Vector2();
        Vector2(const Vector2 & vec);
        Vector2(const float & x, const float & y);
        ~Vector2();

        inline Vector2 & operator=(const Vector2 & rhs);

        inline Vector2 operator+(Vector2 rhs);
        inline Vector2 operator-(Vector2 rhs);
        inline Vector2 operator*(const float & scalar);
        friend inline Vector2 operator*(const float & scalar, Vector2 rhs);

        inline Vector2 & operator+=(const Vector2 & rhs);
        inline Vector2 & operator-=(const Vector2 & rhs);
        inline Vector2 & operator*=(const float & scalar);

        bool operator==(const Vector2 & rhs);
        bool operator!=(const Vector2 & rhs);

        inline Vector2 & operator++();
        inline Vector2 & operator--();

        inline void Normal(Vector2 & rhs);

        Vector2 & Normalize();
        void Normalize(Vector2 & rhs);

        Vector2 & Dot(const Vector2 & rhs1, const Vector2 & rhs2);
        static float Cross(const Vector2 & lhs, Vector2 & rhs);

        float x;
        float y;
    };

    struct Vector3
    {
        Vector3();
        Vector3(const Vector3 & vec);
        Vector3(const float & x, const float & y, const float & z);
        virtual ~Vector3();

        inline Vector3 & operator=(const Vector3 & rhs);

        inline Vector3 operator+(Vector3 rhs);
        inline Vector3 operator-(Vector3 rhs);
        inline Vector3 operator*(const float & scalar);
        friend inline Vector3 operator*(const float & scalar, Vector3 rhs);

        inline Vector3 & operator+=(const Vector3 & rhs);
        inline Vector3 & operator-=(const Vector3 & rhs);
        inline Vector3 & operator*=(const float & rhs);

        inline bool operator==(const Vector3 & rhs);
        inline bool operator!=(const Vector3 & rhs);

        inline Vector3 & operator++();
        inline Vector3 & operator--();

        void Normalize();
        void Normalize(Vector3 rhs);

        void Dot(const Vector3 & vec1, const Vector3 & vec2);
        void Cross(const Vector3 & vec1, const Vector3 & vec2);

        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    };

    struct Vector4
    {
        Vector4();
        Vector4(const Vector4 & rhs);
        Vector4(const float & x, const float & y, const float & z, const float & w);
        ~Vector4();

        inline Vector4 & operator=(const Vector4 & rhs);

        inline Vector4 operator+(Vector4 rhs);
        inline Vector4 operator-(Vector4 rhs);
        inline Vector4 operator*(const float & scalar);
        friend inline Vector4 operator*(const float & scalar, Vector4 rhs);

        inline Vector4 & operator+=(const Vector4 & rhs);
        inline Vector4 & operator-=(const Vector4 & rhs);
        inline Vector4 & operator*=(const float & rhs);

        inline bool operator==(const Vector4 & rhs);
        inline bool operator!=(const Vector4 & rhs);

        inline Vector4 & operator++();
        inline Vector4 & operator--();

        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        float w;
    };

    struct Quaternion
    {
        Quaternion();
        Quaternion(const Quaternion & rhs);
        Quaternion(const Vector3 & v, const float & w);
        ~Quaternion();

        inline Quaternion & operator=(const Quaternion & rhs);

        inline bool operator==(const Quaternion & rhs);
        inline bool operator!=(const Quaternion & rhs);

        inline Quaternion operator*(Quaternion rhs);
        inline Quaternion & mul(const Quaternion & rhs);

        inline void Conjugate();
        inline void Conjugate(Quaternion &);

        inline void Normalize();
        inline void Normalize(Quaternion &);

        Vector3 v;
        float w;
    };


}
#endif
```

SYNC_Vectors.cpp

```
#include "SYNC_Vectors.h"

//-----------------------------------------
// SYNC::Vector2 defintions
//-----------------------------------------

SYNC::Vector2::Vector2()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

SYNC::Vector2::Vector2(const Vector2 & vec)
{
    x = vec.x;
    y = vec.y;
}

SYNC::Vector2::Vector2(const float & ix, const float & iy)
{
    x = ix;
    y = iy;
}

SYNC::Vector2::~Vector2()
{
}

SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::operator=(const SYNC::Vector2 & rhs)
{
    x = rhs.x;
    y = rhs.y;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector2 SYNC::Vector2::operator+(SYNC::Vector2 rhs)
{
    rhs.x += x;
    rhs.y += y;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector2 SYNC::Vector2::operator-(SYNC::Vector2 rhs)
{
    rhs.x -= x;
    rhs.y -= y;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector2 SYNC::Vector2::operator*(const float & scalar)
{
    SYNC::Vector2 ret( x * scalar, y * scalar);

    return ret;
}

SYNC::Vector2 operator*(const float & scalar, SYNC::Vector2 rhs)
{
    rhs.x *= scalar;
    rhs.y *= scalar;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::operator+=(const Vector2 & rhs)
{
    x += rhs.x;
    y += rhs.y;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::operator-=(const Vector2 & rhs)
{
    x -= rhs.x;
    y -= rhs.y;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::operator*=(const float & scalar)
{
    x *= scalar;
    y *= scalar;

    return *this;
}

bool SYNC::Vector2::operator==(const Vector2 & rhs)
{
    if(rhs.x == x && rhs.y == y)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

bool SYNC::Vector2::operator!=(const Vector2 & rhs)
{
    if(rhs.x != x || rhs.y != y)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::operator++()
{
    x++;
    y++;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::operator--()
{
    x--;
    y--;

    return *this;
}

void SYNC::Vector2::Normal(Vector2 & rhs)
{
    rhs.x = y;
    rhs.y = -x;
}

SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::Normalize()
{
    if(x > 0.000001 || y > 0.000001)
    {
        float length = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
        x /= length;
        y /= length;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    return *this;
}

void SYNC::Vector2::Normalize(Vector2 & rhs)
{
    if(x > 0.000001 || y > 0.000001)
    {
        float length = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
        rhs.x = x / length;
        rhs.y = y / length;
    }
    else
    {
        rhs.x = 0;
        rhs.y = 0;
    }
}

SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::Dot(const Vector2 & rhs1, const Vector2 & rhs2)
{
    x = rhs1.x * rhs2.x;
    y = rhs1.y * rhs2.y;

    return *this;
}

float SYNC::Vector2::Cross(const Vector2 & rhs1, Vector2 & rhs2)
{
    return ((rhs1.x * rhs2.y) - (rhs1.y * rhs2.x));
}


//-----------------------------------------
// SYNC::Vector3 defintions
//-----------------------------------------


SYNC::Vector3::Vector3()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
}

SYNC::Vector3::Vector3(const Vector3 & vec)
{
    x = vec.x;
    y = vec.y;
    z = vec.z;
}

SYNC::Vector3::Vector3(const float & ix, const float & iy, const float & iz)
{
    x = ix;
    y = iy;
    z = iz;
}

SYNC::Vector3::~Vector3()
{
}

SYNC::Vector3 & SYNC::Vector3::operator=(const Vector3 & rhs)
{
    x = rhs.x;
    y = rhs.y;
    z = rhs.z;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector3 SYNC::Vector3::operator+(Vector3 rhs)
{
    rhs.x += x;
    rhs.y += y;
    rhs.z += z;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector3 SYNC::Vector3::operator-(Vector3 rhs)
{
    rhs.x -= x;
    rhs.y -= y;
    rhs.z -= z;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector3 SYNC::Vector3::operator*(const float & rhs)
{
    Vector3 ret(x * rhs, y * rhs, z * rhs);
    return ret;
}

SYNC::Vector3 operator*(const float & scalar, SYNC::Vector3 rhs)
{
    rhs.x *= scalar;
    rhs.y *= scalar;
    rhs.z *= scalar;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector3 & SYNC::Vector3::operator+=(const Vector3 & rhs)
{
    x += rhs.x;
    y += rhs.y;
    z += rhs.z;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector3 & SYNC::Vector3::operator-=(const Vector3 & rhs)
{
    x -= rhs.x;
    y -= rhs.y;
    z -= rhs.z;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector3 & SYNC::Vector3::operator*=(const float & rhs)
{
    x *= rhs;
    y *= rhs;
    z *= rhs;

    return *this;
}

bool SYNC::Vector3::operator==(const Vector3 & rhs)
{
    if(x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y && z == rhs.z)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

bool SYNC::Vector3::operator!=(const Vector3 & rhs)
{
    if(x != rhs.x || y != rhs.y || z != rhs.z)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

SYNC::Vector3 & SYNC::Vector3::operator++()
{
    x++;
    y++;
    z++;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector3 & SYNC::Vector3::operator--()
{
    x--;
    y--;
    z--;

    return *this;
}

void SYNC::Vector3::Normalize()
{
    if(x > 0.000001 || y > 0.000001 || z > 0.000001)
    {
        float length = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
        x /= length;
        y /= length;
        z /= length;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
}

void SYNC::Vector3::Normalize(Vector3 rhs)
{
    if(x > 0.000001 || y > 0.000001 || z > 0.000001)
    {
        float length = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
        rhs.x /= length;
        rhs.y /= length;
        rhs.z /= length;
    }
    else
    {
        rhs.x = 0;
        rhs.y = 0;
        rhs.z = 0;
    }
}

void SYNC::Vector3::Dot(const Vector3 & vec1, const Vector3 & vec2)
{
    x = vec1.x * vec2.x;
    y = vec1.y * vec2.y; 
    z = vec1.z * vec2.z;
}

void SYNC::Vector3::Cross(const Vector3 & vec1, const Vector3 & vec2)
{
    x = ((vec1.y * vec2.z) - (vec1.z * vec2.y));
    y = ((vec1.z * vec2.x) - (vec1.x * vec2.z));
    z = ((vec1.x * vec2.y) - (vec1.y * vec2.x));
}

//-----------------------------------------
// SYNC::Vector4 defintions
//-----------------------------------------

SYNC::Vector4::Vector4()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    w = 0;
}

SYNC::Vector4::Vector4(const Vector4 & rhs)
{
    x = rhs.x;
    y = rhs.y;
    z = rhs.z;
    w = rhs.w;

}

SYNC::Vector4::Vector4(const float & ix, const float & iy, const float & iz, const float & iw)
{
    x = ix;
    y = iy;
    z = iz;
    w = iw;
}

SYNC::Vector4::~Vector4()
{
}

SYNC::Vector4 & SYNC::Vector4::operator=(const Vector4 & rhs)
{
    x = rhs.x;
    y = rhs.y;
    z = rhs.z;
    w = rhs.w;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector4 SYNC::Vector4::operator+(Vector4 rhs)
{
    rhs.x += x;
    rhs.y += y;
    rhs.z += z;
    rhs.w += w;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector4 SYNC::Vector4::operator-(Vector4 rhs)
{
    rhs.x += x;
    rhs.y += y;
    rhs.z += z;
    rhs.w += w;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector4 SYNC::Vector4::operator*(const float & rhs)
{
    Vector4 ret( x * rhs, y * rhs, z * rhs, w * rhs);
    return ret;
}

SYNC::Vector4 operator*(const float & scalar, SYNC::Vector4 rhs)
{
    rhs.x *= scalar;
    rhs.y *= scalar;
    rhs.z *= scalar;
    rhs.w *= scalar;

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Vector4 & SYNC::Vector4::operator+=(const Vector4 & rhs)
{
    x += rhs.x;
    y += rhs.y;
    z += rhs.z;
    w += rhs.w;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector4 & SYNC::Vector4::operator-=(const Vector4 & rhs)
{
    x += rhs.x;
    y += rhs.y;
    z += rhs.z;
    w += rhs.w;

    return *this;
}

SYNC::Vector4 & SYNC::Vector4::operator*=(const float & rhs)
{
    x *= rhs;
    y *= rhs;
    z *= rhs;
    w *= rhs;
}

bool SYNC::Vector4::operator==(const Vector4 & rhs)
{
    if(x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y && z == rhs.z && w == rhs.w)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool SYNC::Vector4::operator!=(const Vector4 & rhs)
{
    if(x != rhs.x || y != rhs.y || z != rhs.z || w != rhs.w)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

SYNC::Vector4 & SYNC::Vector4::operator++()
{
    x++;
    y++;
    z++;
    w++;
}

SYNC::Vector4 & SYNC::Vector4::operator--()
{
    x--;
    y--;
    z--;
    w--;
}

//---------------------------------
// SYNC::Quaternion definitions
//---------------------------------

SYNC::Quaternion::Quaternion()
{
    v.x = 0;
    v.y = 0;
    v.z = 0;
    w = 0;
}

SYNC::Quaternion::Quaternion(const Quaternion & rhs)
{
    v.x = rhs.v.x;
    v.y = rhs.v.y;
    v.z = rhs.v.z;
    w = rhs.w;
}

SYNC::Quaternion::Quaternion(const Vector3 & iv, const float & iw)
{
    v = iv;
    w = iw;
}

SYNC::Quaternion::~Quaternion()
{
}

SYNC::Quaternion & SYNC::Quaternion::operator=(const Quaternion & rhs)
{
    v = rhs.v;
    w = rhs.w;
}

bool SYNC::Quaternion::operator==(const Quaternion & rhs)
{
    if(v == rhs.v && w == rhs.w)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool SYNC::Quaternion::operator!=(const Quaternion & rhs)
{
    if(v != rhs.v || w != rhs.w)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

SYNC::Quaternion SYNC::Quaternion::operator*(Quaternion rhs)
{
    rhs.v.x = (w * rhs.v.x) + (v.x * rhs.w)  + (v.y * rhs.v.z) - (v.z * rhs.v.y);
    rhs.v.y = (w * rhs.v.y) - (v.x * rhs.v.z) + (v.y * rhs.w) + (v.z * rhs.v.x);
    rhs.v.z = (w * rhs.v.z) + (v.x * rhs.v.y) - (v.y * rhs.v.x) + (v.z * rhs.w);
    rhs.w = (w * rhs.w) - (v.x * rhs.v.x) - (v.y * rhs.v.y) - (v.z * rhs.v.z); 

    return rhs;
}

SYNC::Quaternion & SYNC::Quaternion::mul(const Quaternion & rhs)
{
    v.x = (w * rhs.v.x) + (v.x * rhs.w)  + (v.y * rhs.v.z) - (v.z * rhs.v.y);
    v.y = (w * rhs.v.y) - (v.x * rhs.v.z) + (v.y * rhs.w) + (v.z * rhs.v.x);
    v.z = (w * rhs.v.z) + (v.x * rhs.v.y) - (v.y * rhs.v.x) + (v.z * rhs.w);
    w = (w * rhs.w) - (v.x * rhs.v.x) - (v.y * rhs.v.y) - (v.z * rhs.v.z); 

    return *this;
}

void SYNC::Quaternion::Conjugate()
{
    v *= -1;
}

void SYNC::Quaternion::Conjugate(Quaternion & rhs)
{
    rhs.v = v * -1;
    rhs.w = w;
}

void SYNC::Quaternion::Normalize()
{
    float length = sqrt((w*w) + (v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z));
    if(length > 0.000001)
    {
        v.x /= length;
        v.y /= length;
        v.z /= length;
        w /= length;
    }
    else
    {
        v.x = 0;
        v.y = 0;
        v.z = 0;
        w = 0;
    }
}

void SYNC::Quaternion::Normalize(Quaternion & rhs)
{
    float length = sqrt((w*w) + (v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z)); 
    if(length > 0.000001)
    {
        rhs.v.x = v.x / length;
        rhs.v.y = v.y / length;
        rhs.v.z = v.z / length;
        rhs.w = w / length;
    }
    else
    {
        rhs.v.x = 0;
        rhs.v.y = 0;
        rhs.v.z = 0;
        rhs.w = 0;
    }
}
```

syncmod.h

```
#ifndef SYNCMOD_H
#define SYNCMOD_H

#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "SYNC_Vectors.h"

struct SYNCMODEL_HEADER
{   
    char id[8];
    short ver[2];
    long m_numOfVertices;
    long m_numOfIndices;
    std::string m_modelName;
};

struct VERTEX_TYPE
{
    SYNC::Vector3 position;
    SYNC::Vector4 color;
    SYNC::Vector3 normal;
    SYNC::Vector3 binormal;
    SYNC::Vector3 tangent;
    SYNC::Vector2 textureCoords;
};

class SYNCMODEL_MATERIAL_HEADER
{
    enum DATA_TYPE{MATERIAL_SHORT , MATERIAL_INT, MATERIAL_LONG, MATERIAL_FLOAT, MATERIAL_DOUBLE};
    struct Data_Index
    {
        DATA_TYPE type;
        char * accessor;
    };

    int m_numOfElements;
    std::map<std::string, Data_Index> m_Indices;

};

std::ifstream & operator>>(std::ifstream & stream, SYNCMODEL_HEADER & header);

#endif
```

syncmod.cpp

```
#include "syncmod.h"

std::ifstream & operator>>(std::ifstream & stream, SYNCMODEL_HEADER & header)
{
    stream.read(header.id, 8);
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&header.ver), sizeof(short) * 2);
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&header.m_numOfVertices), sizeof(long));
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&header.m_numOfIndices), sizeof(long));
    std::getline(stream, header.m_modelName, '\0');
    stream.seekg(static_cast<int>(stream.tellg()) - 1);
    return stream;
}
```

anyone know what the heck is going on here?

edit: Just an additional observation here, why is it throwing up flags with just the assignment operator of these two and not SYNC::Vector3?

Comment: `VERTEX_TYPE` has a compiler-generated assignment operator that does element-by-element assignment, which is probably what's calling the various assignment operators that the compiler is complaining about. See my answer for the solution.

Comment: To the edit: that's strange. They do look like they're all set up the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header `SYNC_Vectors.h` declares:

```
inline Vector2 & operator=(const Vector2 & rhs);
```

and the source file `SYNC_Vectors.cpp` defines:

```
SYNC::Vector2 & SYNC::Vector2::operator=(const SYNC::Vector2 & rhs)
```

Remove the `inline` from the declaration and things should get better. `<g>` Or, as we've discussed, put the definitions of the inline functions into `SYNC_Vectors.h`, either by copying the text or with a `#include` directive at the end of the file. For the latter, most people use a distinctive extension, often `.inl`.

Comment: removing inline did nothing :\ . inline merely tells the compiler to replace a function call with the actual contents of the function during compilation. It is still the same function declaration and definition.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why it did nothing. Did you compile and link with `SYNC_Vectors.cpp`? `inline` tells the compiler that multiple definitions are okay, and it requires that the definition of the function be visible at every point where it's called. Putting the definition in a .cpp file won't work if the function is called from some other translation unit, because it's not visible there. That's why inline functions are always defined in header files.

Comment: With msvc, I can never tell when a .cpp is linked or not. I do however use it sporatically through code that i know is compiled, and it is indeed, included in the build. So your saying that inline allows for two different definitions of the same function? one with inline and one without? how does it differentiate between the two? Also, let me just move the inline functions into the header and see what happens.

Comment: inline allows multiple **identical** definitions. For example, `inline int min(int a, int b) { return a < b ? a : b; }`. You can put this in a header file and #include that header wherever it's needed. In a translation unit that hasn't seen the inline definition, it's okay to provide an out-of-line definition, but that's rare and confusing.

Comment: Now it works, and i'm actually left with more questions :\ . 1) why does the VERTEX_TYPE class need these two assignment operators. 2) why does it aparently not need SYNC::Vector3::operator= 3) and last, should i keep it as a rule of thumb that, if i declare an inline member function, i should ALWAYS define it within the header?

Comment: 1) Somewhere, an object of type `VERTEX_TYPE` is being assigned, so the compiler generates an assignment operator. 2) I don't know; that's strange. 3) Yes, that's the right approach. Some folks like to put the function definitions in a separate file, then `#include` that file at the end of the header that declares the inline functions.

Comment: I take back what I said before, that "In a translation unit that hasn't seen the inline definition, it's okay to provide an out-of-line definition". It's not, but the compiler is not required to complain about that.

Comment: 1) i can almost guarantee that at no point am i using VERTEX_TYPE::operator= but I guess i can't argue with the compiler :(  2) ikr? 3) i like this suggestion, and i'm gonna do just that. If you could edit your answer to reflect what we've discussed here, i'll accept tout suite :) .